# For a Windows 2008 R2 as a Hyper-V client should I install SERVERSTANDARD OR SERVERSTANDARDV?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm setting up a test "server" on my laptop with Hyper-V. When I go to install from an MSDN ISO I have two choices for standard edition. SERVERSTANDARD or SERVERSTANDARDV.

Googling gives me lists of cracked windows keys, but one site claims that SERVERSTANDARDV is the non Hyper-V flavor. I assume that doesn't contain the Hyper-V server, but wold be safe for a Hyper-V client? I ask because the install failed repeatedly on me, and before I started troubleshooting I wanted to to eliminate the obvious.

To be precise, I am installing a [checked build of Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (basically a debug compile of the entire OS), and the file I downloaded from MSDN is `en_windows_server_2008_r2_standard_enterprise_datacenter_and_web_debug_checked_build_x64_dvd_408075.iso`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should install the same version of the OS in your test environment as you do or will in production.  Seeing as how the ServerStandardV edition isn't widely used (or available anymore, for that matter), I'd hope you're not deploying it into production, and therefore recommend using the "normal" Standard edition.

And, as I recall, ServerStandardV was actually Server Standard -V (without Hyper V).  I'm trying to find an official source on that, but it seems irritatingly illusive.

### EDIT:

Ah, can't find an official source that's linkable, but visiting the MS Volume Licensing Center, I do have the option to download the "without Hyper-V version" and it shows up as [edition]ServerV on the install dialogue.  Screenies to come.

Comment: @HopelessNoob there will not be a production environment. This is purely to hook up WinDbg to.